# Eeeek! Code blocks are misbehaving!

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

So code blocks in questions and answers on the android app (inline included) seem to be scared of me putting my finger in them.
When I poke them, they only move over two columns!

(For clarity, these are the code blocks that overlap the TextArea view because they've been eating too much)

The intended behaviour here is that when I press my finger into a code block, the touch event should register a drag; at current, I try to scroll inside a code block and I end up switching to question or answer view instead, over and over.

**EDIT:**

Something tells me this is status-bydesign because the text is deliberately cut off (probably inviting you to click on the code block and expand it; UX Decision?):
[image]

Comment: Leave those poor code blocks alone!!!

Comment: So you've been poking code blocks, have you? I see.....have you been peeking as well?

Comment: @Bart is that supposed to be a double entente with BASIC?

Comment: Ah @ColeJohnson, the innocence of youth to even have to ask. ;)

Comment: What phone are you using? Also, is this happening in the view you get after tapping on a code block to view it full screen?

Comment: Will I get many upvotes if I start my question title with "Eeeeeek!"?

Comment: Add freehand red circles, Unicorns, and mumble about oscillation, and you've hit the rep-cap right there @H2CO3.

Comment: @Bart gimme a second. It's going to be magical.

Comment: @Bart Eeeeeeek, I didn't even think about that!

Comment: @ColeJohnson [WAT?](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Comment: The freehand circle definitely helped. I don't think it's a by-design thing so I'll take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. Starting in version 0.1.5 those code blocks won't be scrollable at all unless tapped, which should be less confusing.

Comment: Please mention somewhere around the code block "Tap to expand" or something. It's not very intuitive.

Comment: **Bug not fixed.** I'm using 0.1.50, and the same problem still exists - when tap-dragging at the code block the code block scrolls for a few pixels first, and then the tab switch is triggered. The tapping does cause the block to appear in it's own, scrollable popup, though.

Comment: The described solution really seems like a bad UX solution. I would think the intuitive behaviour would be that the smaller element takes precedence, because you can always tap-drag outside it to trigger the tab switch. The expanded popup dedicated for the block is still good, though.

Comment: Hi Kasra, sorry for commenting on the old post, but it seems since the change to use `RecyclerView` for question-and-answer, the code block now can be horizontally scrolled without the need to pop-up the code-block. Is this intended? (also, the indicator on the top-right is moving when horizontally scrolled). If it's not intended, then I'll post a bug report.

Comment: It would be sad to have to pop open a code block (out of context) to scroll it. Then you mostly can't see the other code blocks and the intervening description text (literate programming style). The example in this Question has 3 code blocks. Not being able to see them together means you need to remember them when trying to read and analyze them.

Comment: @AndrewT. authoritative answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248524/229741 -- Consider this bug outdated