# Horizontal scrolling broken by vertical motion

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

In the Android app, it's very challenging to horizontally scroll a code block (or news feed) because with a little bit of vertical motion it switches to vertical scrolling and won't switch back. Scrolling should not be challenging.

Maybe some of you folks with steadier hands don't notice this but I find it very frustrating.

Can you please fix it to do free 2D scrolling rather than 1D with vertical capturing? Or, second best, give it a significant vertical tolerance before capture?

**Edit:** App version 1.0.56 on Android Lollipop 5.0.1 on Nexus 5.

Comment: Heard you the first time:)

Comment: Did you forget that you posted this question 15 minutes earlier?

Comment: No. The post have an error message. I gave it several minutes but still couldn't see the post. I tried again. Same result. Gave up. Your comment provided a notification which is the first indication that either post went in.

Comment: I still can't see either post except via your notification. Thanks, @martinjames !

Comment: Your interwebs are even more screwed up than mine:(

Comment: @AndrewT. When you scroll, say, a code block horizontally it only works if you move your finger perfectly horizontally. Any vertical motion switches it to vertical scrolling, locking the horizontal position. This is different form the bug you linked. I get it on my nexus 6. App version is 1.0.56.

Comment: Also,  it's not particularly annoying for me but I could see how it could be for some people. I'd label this as a usability issue instead of a bug.

Comment: Actually I just tried it out again and it is incredibly annoying. No idea how I hadn't noticed it before.

Comment: Thanks @andrewt . I added the version info. And it is a different scrolling bug.

Comment: Moved this over to Meta.SE, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: As of version 1.0.57 (coming out later today) this is fixed. You can now scroll horizontally on code blocks or tap on them to view them in the bigger view, and a minor swipe up or down while you're scrolling the code block won't cause a "jump" movement.

---

Story time:

Originally viewing a question and answer page in our application looked like this:

[image: Question and Answer view]

Questions and answers were separated by tabs that you could swipe to switch between. As a result, trying to scroll a code block horizontally lead to a collision with the base view's horizontal scrolling for switching between the two. So, we made code blocks clickable to open them in a new overlay where this wouldn't be an issue. That's what the little triangle on the top right represents.

As of a few months ago, answers are now *below* questions like they are on the sites. When we made this change however, we forgot to go back and think about the process that had resulted in what we have for code block functionality. The current ability to horizontal slide a little in the code blocks is actually a bug, looking at the code you can see what's causing it:

```
    String blockOverflowValue = allowBlockScrolling ? "auto" : "hidden";
    String defaultStyle = "<style>html { -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: " + fontSize + "; }\n" +
                          "body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }\n";
    if (allowBlockScrolling)
        defaultStyle += "pre, blockquote { -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; overflow: " + blockOverflowValue + "; background-color: #eee; }\n";
```

`allowBlockScrolling` is a parameter that's set for views that *should* be scrollable (e.g. looking at a code block in the post-click overlay view), but as you can see when that is set to `false` (as it is for the base question & answer views) we are actually not setting anything to make the code not scrollable, which is causing the weird functionality of small jump-like scrolls you are seeing.

So, the code is currently trying to stop horizontal sliding on all code blocks but due to that bug it's failing and causing what's happening here, but you know what: Now that we don't have the collision with the Q&A tabs you *should* be able to horizontally scroll code blocks.

This is what I'm working on right now. As of the next update (1.0.57+) you will be able to seamlessly scroll code blocks while viewing a question, and if you would like you can still tap them to view a bigger-screen version of the code in an overlay.

Comment: Right on! Should I accept this "answer" (design) now or wait until I can verify the released fix? (Bug tracking != Q&A.)

Comment: @Jerry101 I'll wait until I finish my fix to mark this question with the status-completed tag, then you can mark this as accepted after you've seen it in action (hopefully later today or by Monday)

Comment: The fix is in and it's very pleasant indeed.

Comment: Glad to hear it :)